# Create HTML table with Firebase Data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database set up that I need to create an HTML table with that necessary info. Below is how I have set up my firebase data.

```
{
  "Markets" : {
    "Athens" : {
      "Item" : {
        "name" : "Beef",
        "price" : 10,
        "salePrice" : 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I have my HTML table set up and my code to attempt to retrieve the data. The table is appropriately being created but I am not seeing any data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th>Price:</th> 
    <th>Sale Price:</th>

 </table> 

<script>
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.price + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.salePrice + '</td>';

                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're reading the root node. There are a few more levels of data in your JSON before you get to the `name`, `price` and `salesPrice` properties. You'll either need to navigate those levels in your callback, or in your query. An example of the latter:

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('Markets/Athens').once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            content +='<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.price + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.salePrice + '</td>';

            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: This still didn't return any values? It's only returning my table header text values.